# Animating Fab on click (zoom in/out)

Tags: java, android, animation, android-animation, floating-action-button

I am trying to mimic animation and the color change for the following floating action button.

The way the floating action button works is white is off and blue is on.

[image]

However, I have been unsuccessful with the animation and changing the color.

These have been my attempts at doing this, as you can see I have commented out all the different ways I have tried to do this.

This is my code:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @OnClick(R.id.fabMovieFavourite)
    public void addMovieFavourite(View view) {
 /*       final Animator animator = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getActivity(), R.animator.add_favourite_movie);
        animator.setTarget(view);)
        animator.start();
 */
/*
        AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
        PropertyValuesHolder propertyValuesHolderX = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.SCALE_X, 1.1f);
        PropertyValuesHolder propertyValuesHolderY = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.SCALE_Y, 1.1f);
        ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(view, propertyValuesHolderX, propertyValuesHolderY);
        objectAnimator.setDuration(300);
        objectAnimator.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator(10f));
*/

        /*
        objectAnimator.setRepeatCount(1);
        objectAnimator.setRepeatMode(ObjectAnimator.REVERSE);
*/

/*
        PropertyValuesHolder propertyValuesHolderX2 = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.SCALE_X, 0.9f);
        PropertyValuesHolder propertyValuesHolderY2 = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.SCALE_Y, 0.9f);
        ObjectAnimator objectAnimator2 = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(view, propertyValuesHolderX2, propertyValuesHolderY2);
        objectAnimator.setDuration(300);
        objectAnimator2.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator(10f));

        animatorSet.playSequentially(objectAnimator, objectAnimator2);
        objectAnimator.start();
*/

      //  view.BackgroundTintList(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getContext(), R.color.primary));
        //view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.primary));

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Timber.d("start translationZ");
            ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, View.TRANSLATION_Z, 12f);
            objectAnimator.setDuration(300);
            objectAnimator.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator(10f));
            objectAnimator.setTarget(view);
            objectAnimator.start();
        }
    }
```

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: what I'd try is to use two FABs. fade out and hide one, while fade in and show the other.

Comment: @AngelKoh I am looking for a solution in just using 1 fab

Comment: @ant2009 well I have achieved this thing with the help of library https://github.com/jd-alexander/LikeButton well if  you like to implement this ...I can help...it...

Comment: @PN10 thanks, I will take a look at it

Answer (score 59, accepted):

There're two phases in this animation. First one scales X and Y axis, and second one downscales it. So, we can divide them into two `AnimatorSet`s and play them sequentially.

The key point of the animation is to find appropriate interpolator for the second `AnimatorSet`, because it's not standard one.

[image]

See, we want fab to overshoot, then undershoot and then finally settle up to the specified value in the animator.

Luckily, there's very handy `PathInterpolator`, which will create an interpolator for us with provided `Path`.

```
Path path = new Path();
path.moveTo(0.0f, 0.0f);
path.lineTo(0.5f, 1.3f);
path.lineTo(0.75f, 0.8f);
path.lineTo(1.0f, 1.0f);
PathInterpolator pathInterpolator = new PathInterpolator(path);
```

So, let's create the first animation:

```
final float from = 1.0f;
final float to = 1.3f;

ObjectAnimator scaleX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fab, View.SCALE_X, from, to);
ObjectAnimator scaleY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fab, View.SCALE_Y,  from, to);
ObjectAnimator translationZ = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fab, View.TRANSLATION_Z, from, to);

AnimatorSet set1 = new AnimatorSet();
set1.playTogether(scaleX, scaleY, translationZ);
set1.setDuration(100);
set1.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());

set1.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        fab.setImageResource(isActive ? R.drawable.heart_active : R.drawable.heart_passive);
        fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(isActive ? colorActive : colorPassive));
        isActive = !isActive;
    }
});
```

We are scaling both x, y. Also, we are changing z translation to have appropriate shadow effect. When animation ends, we want to change fab state (color of heart and fab background).

Now let's create the animation to settle back:

```
ObjectAnimator scaleXBack = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fab, View.SCALE_X, to, from);
ObjectAnimator scaleYBack = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fab, View.SCALE_Y, to, from);
ObjectAnimator translationZBack = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fab, View.TRANSLATION_Z, to, from);

AnimatorSet set2 = new AnimatorSet();
set2.playTogether(scaleXBack, scaleYBack, translationZBack);
set2.setDuration(300);
set2.setInterpolator(pathInterpolator);
```

See here, we used `pathInterpolator` that we created earlier.

We want to play those two `AnimatorSet`s sequentially:

```
final AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
set.playSequentially(set1, set2);

set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        fab.setClickable(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
        fab.setClickable(false);
    }
});
```

Also, we want to disable clicks on fab whilst animating it. So we are turning it on/off depending on animation state.

Finally, we launch the animation when a click happens:

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        set.start();
    }
});
```

Result:

[image]

**[Source code at github](https://github.com/azizbekian/FabAnim)**

Comment: One of, if not the best breakdowns of setting up animations I have ever seen. Thank you for going to this length to answer this question, it has been a great help.

Comment: hey @azizbekian can u help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53577838/how-to-animate-a-fab-button-zoom-in-out-continuously the above code is working fine un lolipop and above device but not working in kitkat