# Give a delay after repeat animation

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-animation, android-view

I am adding a infinite animation to my `ImageView`.
Below is my animation code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="70%"
    android:pivotY="70%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:startOffset="2000"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:toXScale="0.8"
    android:toYScale="0.8" />
```

and java code is:

```
Animation pulse = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.pulse);
reviewImage.startAnimation(pulse);
```

the problem is that it make delay after each animation like expand+delay+collapse+delay both i want to give delay only after one cycle means after expand+collapse+delay

Comment: android:repeatMode="reverse" this is reverse animation

Comment: I see, now noticed.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do that with one animation, because the way it works is that it performs animation and will delay the next animation by 2000ms (as specified in xml). From framework's point of view those animations are not connected to each other and it cannot assess them as one animation, so those are two separate animations.

You have to create 2 animations and play them sequentially.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43261561/animating-fab-on-click-zoom-in-out/43304582#43304582) how to do that with `AnimatorSet`s, but you may as well do it with `xml`.

```
<set>

    <scale 
        android:duration="500"
        .../>

    <scale
        android:startOffset="500"
        .../>

</set>
```