# Swipe actions menu on RecyclerView focus and swipe back issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout, swipe-gesture

I'm trying to implement a simple swipe actions menu in a RecyclerView, and i tried to use a simple approach using an ItemTouchHelper and a layout (for each row) containing the row itself and the buttons attached **below** the row. I should show them on swipe.

While the layout work as expected, i still have many important issues. Here's a screenshot:

[image: current layout]

The issues are the following:

- I need to click 3 times over the buttons to make the touch happen
- When i do, i cannot swipe the row back in place, unless i click on it again and drag it from the very end of the row. If i don't click the buttons, i can swipe the row back normally.

This is the simple ItemTouchHelper callback i'm using at the moment:

```
class FileSwipeCallback :
    ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(1, 1) {

    override fun getMovementFlags(
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    ): Int {
        return if (viewHolder is FileAdapter.FileViewHolder) {
            val swipeFlags = ItemTouchHelper.START or ItemTouchHelper.END
            makeMovementFlags(0, swipeFlags)
        } else 0
    }

    override fun onMove(
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
        target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    ): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) { }

    override fun onChildDraw(
        c: Canvas,
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
        dX: Float,
        dY: Float,
        actionState: Int,
        isCurrentlyActive: Boolean
    ) {
        if (actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE) {
            // Swipe left
            if (dX < 0) {
                (viewHolder as FileAdapter.FileViewHolder).itemView.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(
                    R.id.fileItemActions
                ).visibility = View.VISIBLE
                val transitionX = 0.295f * dX
                getDefaultUIUtil().onDraw(
                    c,
                    recyclerView,
                    (viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(
                        R.id.fileInfoRow
                    )),
                    transitionX,
                    dY,
                    actionState,
                    isCurrentlyActive
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'd really appreciate a solution. I already searched here on Stack Overflow, but i only found unclear or partial solutions.

EDIT: updated the question with the new and more classic two layers approach. The visible result is the same, but the issues are changed.

Comment: This seems to be three related but separate questions. Regarding not being able to click the revealed buttons, are you saying that they lie outside the body of the  _ConstraintLayout_ by setting the appropriate constraints and you control the visibility with clipchildren=false? So they slide in from the right as the view holder is moved left?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And yes, there are 3 different problems, but most importantly I'd like to know if this approach is even possible

Comment: Ok, but you didn't answer my question. Check out this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52703823/6287910). You may find it useful. Take a look at all the answers and not just the accepted one.

Comment: This means that my approach is impossible to use, right? i can't find a way to detect touches outside the constraint

Comment: Buttons have to be within the bounds of their parent to be clickable. This is due to the nature of [how touches work in Android](https://medium.com/@suragch/how-touch-events-are-delivered-in-android-eee3b607b038). Even if the buttons are positioned within the _ConstraintLayout_, I think that you will still have trouble with the buttons because of how _ItemTouchHelper_ works.

Comment: I updated the question using a more classic "double view in a frame layout" approach, but i'm still having weird issues. Thanks for the explanation though, i was sure there was some hacky way to make the buttons clickable, but i was terribly wrong :)

Comment: Here's a [library (SwipeRevealLayout)](https://github.com/chthai64/SwipeRevealLayout) that may help. I can't vouch for it, but it may give you some ideas.